# Создание графика с датами на оси X с помощью библиотеки ZedGraph

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Добрый день, пытаюсь сделать график с числом посещений на оси Y и датами на оси X.
Кол-во посещений за каждый день хранится в List а даты в формате 
"yyyy-mm-dd" в List. Вопрос, надо ли переводить даты в формат Date или возможно построить точки используя double и string?

Comment: Вам подошел ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [Пример](http://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/AxisFormat) по идее надо переводить но без времени, если не війдет

```
double date = Convert.ToSingle(DateTime.Now);
MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
```